# Does a PDF file need execution permissions?

Tags: permissions, pdf

What are reasonable PDF file permissions?

Lately I've found that inside a directory, with many PDF files, all files have all possible permissions set on. Being uncomfortable with that I thought about changing them. However, I don't know what be reasonable for PDF files considering that I want to be able to open and, sometimes, change them (e.g. PDF "text maker").

Here a print-screen for how I've found them (`file_1.pdf`), and how I consider to change them(`file_2.pdf`).

[image: This is an example for how (file_1.pdf) I've found them, and how I consider to change them(file_2.pdf)]

I suppose that the initial permission set was lost while I've copied them from a backup HDD. Could you please consider example-peaking a effective way of copying them around without loosing their permission settings. Thank you.

Comment: No, you don't need execution permission. Does your backup hdd have FAT partition, maybe?

Comment: @jimmij Thank you. It was a NTFS formatted HDD. Kusalananda & Hauke Laging seem to pointed the right reason for the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a PDF file is not an executable binary or script and should never need to be executable.

Assuming the documents live on a Unix filesystem, you may remove the executable bits using

```
chmod a-x *.pdf
```

If some of your file systems are non-Unix file systems, the permissions on your files may be messed up like this regardless of how you copy the files around between them.  On Unix file systems, I tend to use `rsync -a` (or `rsync --archive)` to copy files between hosts or local directories to preserve permissions and timestamps.

Comment: With the help of @AlikElzin-kilaka 's [answer from StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377606/chmod-recursively) it was possible to change all PDF files' permissions of all subdirectories by using following (Debian Stretch) bash terminal command in one step: `find . -name "*.pdf" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

Answer (score 3):

If you copy from and to a Linux file system then you use

```
cp -a
```

for keeping the metadata.

If you are copying back from a non-Linux file system like FAT or NTFS then you can use

```
cp -r --no-preserve=mode
```

so that the execute permission is dropped.

If you copy files to a non-Linux file system then you should use a Linux archive tool like `tar`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your answer gives the most and key background information -- FAT/NTFS HDDs -- and how to avoid the problem. However you are not answering directly the question about PDF permissions. Therefore only the up-vote.

Comment: @alex I did not mention that because the other answer already did and I did not want to repeat that. However, I do not care much about my answers getting accepted anyway so no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Read only permission is normally ok, if you only need to read them. However, if you want to modify and replace them, you need also write permission. Therefore I would consider the permission of the second file as sufficient.

For copying the files and keep the permissions use:
"cp -a source dest"

The "-a" attribute copies recursive, preserves all attributes and preserves links. See "man cp".